CSV Output in Python not quite appearing as intended
At the company I work for, we have an in-house written program for quarterly Wi-Fi scans. The code will essentially stop working once we migrate to Windows 11 due to deprecated areas. I'm not trying to fix that.  What I'm trying to do is modernize it by writing it in a more modern language. My language of choice is Python.
See below code:
# Import Third-Party Modules Necessary
import comtypes
import pywifi
import csv
import io

choice = input('''\t\tN: Northern Atrium
               \tNE: Northeastern Atrium
               \tE: Eastern Atrium
               \tSE: Southeastern Atrium
               \tS: Southern Atrium
               \tSW: Southwestern Atrium
               \tW: Western Atrium
               \tNW: Northwestern Atrium
               \tK: Kitchen
               \tI: IT Area
               \tV: Vacations Area
               \tT: Travelstore Area
               \tD: Denise Office
               \tM: Meetings Area
               \tR: Reception
               \tPlease enter the location that is being scanned: ''')


# Execute Wi-Fi Scan
wifi = pywifi.PyWiFi()
iface = wifi.interfaces()[0]
iface.scan()
results = iface.scan_results()

# Creates the csv file and populates field names in the first row
with io.open('Wifi-Scan.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    fieldnames = ['BSSID', 'SSID', 'Signal', 'Location']
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    #Creates the link between fieldnames and variables
    for network in results:
        bssid = network.bssid
        ssid = network.ssid
        signal = network.signal

        # Case for inputting location
        match choice:
            case 'N':
                location = "Northern Atrium"
            case 'NE':
                location = "Northeastern Atrium"
            case 'E':
                location = "Eastern Atrium"
            case 'SE':
                location = "Southeastern Atrium"
            case 'S':
                location = "Southern Atrium"
            case 'SW':
                location = "Southwestern Atrium"
            case 'W':
                location = "Western Atrium"
            case 'NW':
                location = "Northwestern Atrium"
            case 'K':
                location = "Kitchen"
            case 'I':
                location = "IT Area"
            case 'V':
                location = "Vacations"
            case 'T':
                location = "Travelstore Area"
            case 'D':
                location = "Denise's Office"
            case 'M':
                location = "Meetings Area"
            case 'R':
                location = "Reception"

        # Writes the scan results into the fields
        writer.writerow({bssid, ssid, signal, location})

It runs. It pulls the data. It writes to the CSV file. However, it does not quite format the CSV data as intended. See below actual output:
| BSSID             | SSID              | Signal          | Location        | 
| Home              | b0:95:75:46:45:d1 | -36             | Northern Atrium |
| Home              | b0:95:75:46:45:d2 | Northern Atrium | -62             |
| 78:76:89:97:04:e2 |                   | Western Atrium  | -83             |
|                   | -62               | Kimsuezun       | Western Atrium  |

Basically, it seems like the fields are getting mixed up.  This is the third write of my code with making use of pypi documentation for pywifi, csv, and comtypes functionalities.  Also of note, I am not a professional programmer. I am a Systems Administrator, but it is an expectation at this job for IT to know enough to do some basic things. I don't think this is a basic thing, therefore even getting to this point took a lot of research.
I was expecting a CSV file output with the fields lining up.  I have read through the documentation for pywifi, comtypes, and csv to ensure that my syntax is correct and that the functionality I am looking for exists.

{bssid, ssid, signal, location} is a set. You might have gotten mixed up with syntax from another language there.

@user2357112 that is entirely possible.  I will try removing the set delimiters first thing tomorrow and let y'all know if it fixes the issue.

@user2357112 you were correct in that the set identification was the issue.  It is working as intended now.  Thank you so much!
